# What does Metacharacter and backslash do here?

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Regular Expressions from some website, and I am having some trouble understanding usage of metacharacters and usage of backslashes in raw string.

```
import re

pattern = r"(.+) \1"

match = re.match(pattern, "word word")   
if match:
   print ("Match 1")

match = re.match(pattern, "?! ?!")
if match:
   print ("Match 2")    

match = re.match(pattern, "abc cde")
if match:
   print ("Match 3")
```

My main doubt is the use of (.+) here and the backslash used. What would be the output if instead of 1 it was 2? I know + means "one or more repetitions".

Comment: `\1` is back-reference of captured group #1 which is `(.+)`

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
r"(.+) \1"
```

means that `\1` should match what is captured exactly by the first group. It didn't match `"abc cde"` because first group captured `abc` the so it's like you are matching this:  `re.match(r'abc abc', text)`. 
This called back reference a group.

For example you need to match a text that start end ends with the same letters:

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w).+\1"

match = re.match(pattern, "ABA")  # OK
match = re.match(pattern, "ABC")  # NO
```

Another example match text that start with 3 letters and ends with this letters in the inverse order

```
import re

pattern = r"(\w)(\w)(\w)\3\2\1"
re.match(pattern, 'ABCCBA') # OK
re.match(pattern, 'ABCCBC') # NO
```

**Note:** you can only back-reference only a **capturing group**, means that this is not valid  `(?:.+) \1` because
the first group will match and not capture anything so you cannot back-reference it.

**Edits**

- `+`   which matches one or more times, requires at least one occurrence
- `*`   matches zero or more times

`ca+t`  match `cat, caat , caaat` :  matches `c` followed by at least one `a` or more  followed by `t`.

`ca+t`  match `ct, cat , caaaaat` :  matches `c` followed by zero or or more  `a`  followed by `t`

Comment: what is the role of + metacharacter. Please specify.

Comment: check my edits Hope this make thing clear